# Who allocates the memory for control block of shared_ptr when using custom new() operator with a class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, new-operator

Suppose I have a code like this:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void* p);
};


int main() {
    auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
    return 0; 
}
```

The `shared_ptr` will create separate *control-block* and *object-block*. I suppose the memory for the object block will be created using the `Foo::operator new()`. Is the memory for the *control-block* created using `::operator new()` or `Foo::operator new()`? And in case of `make_shared`, would the entire single-block of memory be allocated using `Foo::operator new()`?

Comment: `shared_ptr` never needs to allocate an object-block on it's own. You passed in a pointer, it can just use that directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The shared_ptr will create separate control-block and object-block.  I suppose the memory for the object block will be created using the Foo::operator new().

Nope. You already passed in the pointer to the object, so it only needs a control block. In fact, I believe no shared_ptr construction allocates a single object-block, they never need it.

> Is the memory for the control-block created using ::operator new() or Foo::operator new()?

C++ spec doesn't specify, but the sane thing for an implementation to do is rebind the allocator to an `Allocator<ControlBlock>` and use its `allocate` member, which will almost certainly use `::operator new()`. It's allocating a `ControlBlock`, not a `Foo`.

> And in case of make_shared, would the entire single-block of memory be allocated using Foo::operator new()?

The C++ spec does specify this one:

> 3.11.3.6 ... The allocate_shared templates use a copy of a (rebound for an unspecified value_type) to allocate memory...
>
> 7 Remarks: (7.1) — Implementations should perform no more than one memory allocation. [ Note: This provides efficiency equivalent to an intrusive smart pointer. — end note ]>

In this case, the implementation will rebind the allocator to an `Allocator<ControlAndObjectBlock>` and use its `allocate` member, which will almost certainly again use `::operator new()`, since it's allocating a `ControlAndObjectBlock` instead of a `Foo`.

summary: Since shared_ptr never actually allocates an object block by itself, it'll never use `Foo::operator new`. However, your `std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo())` expression allocates a `Foo` using `Foo::operator new`, and then constructs a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` from that pointer.